# How can I pass one class value into another class using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one class as below:

public class Module3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
findElement1 a = new findElement1();
driver.get("webAddress");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Username']")).sendKeys("A1");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("1");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginBox']/form/p/button")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainNav']/li[2]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='addNewEntryButton']")).click();


WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select"));
List<WebElement> dropOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("Option"));
for (int i=0; i<dropOptions.size(); i++)
{
 System.out.println(dropOptions.get(i).getText());
}
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("5");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/input")).sendKeys("5");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='saveEntryButton']")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000L);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/header/div/button[4]")).click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    a.findValue();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'submit')]")).click();


    }
```

}

Class2:

public class FindElement1 {
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

```
public void findValue() {
     driver.get("webaddress");
     By by = By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'submit')]");
     isElementPresent(by);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));

 }
public boolean isElementPresent(By by){
      try{
        driver.findElements(by);
        System.out.println("execute");
       return true;
      }
      catch(NoSuchElementException e){
       return false;
      }
}
```

}

I want to execute class2's operation into class1 with class1's value in the mentioned place of a.findValue();Is it possible to pass the driver value of class1 into class2

Comment: As I have understood, you want to keep some common things in a class (such as existence of element, text, WebDriver instance etc.) that can be used from other classes when you need. If I am right to understand your requirement please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Common class in which common things can be kept and be used for any class:

```
package keya;    
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class Common {
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    public Common(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public boolean isElementPresent(By by){
        try{
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you are being tested Module3, the code should be as below:

```
package keya;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Module3 extends Common{

    public static void main(String...strings) throws Exception{
        Common c = new Common();
        driver.get("webAddress");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Username']")).sendKeys("A1");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("1");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginBox']/form/p/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainNav']/li[2]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='addNewEntryButton']")).click();
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select"));
        List<WebElement> dropOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("Option"));
        for (int i=0; i<dropOptions.size(); i++)
        {
         System.out.println(dropOptions.get(i).getText());
        }
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("5");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='timeEntryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/input")).sendKeys("5");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='saveEntryButton']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/header/div/button[4]")).click();
        //Here is the verification whether Submit button is present or not
        c.isElementPresent(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'submit')]"));
        //Rest of the code is here
    }
}
```

So You can use isElementPresent() method of Common class for any number of class/module. You can write more class by extending Common class so that you can use some common methods and WebDriver is being instantiated one time only in Common class.

Comment: The above code is written as java application. If you use TestNG or JUnit as verification tool the code might be more organized.

Comment: for Module3: you have written Module3 class extending Common class. If you like to test another, you can write as Module4 extends Common and can use common things from Common class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just remove the static keyword for the WebDriver from your second class, and create a setter or constructor with the WebDriver.

Instantiate this in your first class and set the WebDriver with your setter or constructor.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by using constructor